# How can I add bootstrap 5 toast in vuejs while redirecting to another page (like form submission)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, bootstrap-5

How can I add `bootstrap5` **toast** in **vuejs** while *redirecting* to another page.
for eg: when we submit the form and redirect to another page, on that page I want a toast  with a message your

> form is submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`eventbus`](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/events-api.html) or [`Vuex`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/). Below is simple example with vuex. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-3-vuex-4-vue-router-forked-v2rcm?file=/src/App.vue) is working demo with Vue3.

```js
const { Toast } = bootstrap

const Home = {
  template: `
    <div>
      <h5>Home</h5>
      <router-link to="/1">Page 1</router-link>
    </div>
  `
}

const Page = {
  template: `
    <div>
      <h5>Page 1</h5>
      <form>
        <h6>Form</h6>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="handleSubmit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  `,
  methods: {
    handleSubmit() {
      this.$store.dispatch('setToast', true)
      this.$router.push('/')
    }
  }
};

const routes = [
  { path: '', component: Home },
  { path: '/1', component: Page }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
});

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    toast: false
  },
  mutations: {
    updateToast(state, payload) {
      state.toast = payload;
    }
  },
  actions: {
    setToast({ commit }, data) {
      commit("updateToast", data);
    },
  },
  getters: {
    getToast(state) {
      return state.toast;
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  router,
  store,
  methods: {
    submitHandler() {
      const toast = new Toast(this.$refs.toast)
      toast.show()
      this.$store.dispatch('setToast', false)
    }
  },
  computed: {
    toastState() {
      return this.$store.getters.getToast
    }
  },
  watch: {
    toastState(newT, oldT) {
      if (newT) this.submitHandler()
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h3>Demo</h3>
  <router-view></router-view>
  <div class="position-fixed bottom-0 end-0 p-3" style="z-index: 11">
    <div id="liveToast" class="toast" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true" ref="toast">
      <div class="toast-header">
        <img src="..." class="rounded me-2" alt="...">
        <strong class="me-auto">TOAST</strong>
        <small>just now</small>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="toast-body">
        form is submitted.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you please show this on Vue CLI format

Comment: @Aminu Aminaldo hey mate , it's the same format `const Page` and `const Home` are plain single file vue templates (Page.vue, Home.vue), and part with `new Vue` is App.vue

Comment: Thank you, Sir But I'm using Vue3, So in Vue 3, $on, $off, and $once have been removed.

Comment: hey mate, take a look now, I updated answer , it is with vue2 but it's the same with vue3

Comment: okay let my try this and thanks for the help

Comment: bro, I'm confused while changing this to Vue CLI format. I'm not getting the result. Can you make this little clear on Vue CLI

Comment: I just updated my answer , you can find link to sandbox with vue-cli, vue3...

Comment: **It worked, Thanks a lot. @nikola**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241645/discussion-between-aminu-aminaldo-and-nikola-pavicevic).